# How to modify a master/aspx file in pre or post build events in Visual Studio and MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

I have an asp.net master file which contains a url with a query string for a css file. I would like to automatically modify the query string every time I do a build, either in the pre or post build events in Visual Studio 2010 or MSBuild. I can write a program to do this but I would rather use some built-in way. The query string can be a random number or the new version number of the assembly or incrementing the number already in the query string.

How can I do this in one of those events? It's more important to do this using MSbuild from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the FileUpdate task in the MSBuild Community Tasks project: https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks